# How do define a function like Function.prototype.call() in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

The `call` method of a function type has a similar signature to the source function, but with one extra parameter at the beginning of the list to serve as the new `this` of the new function.

How can I declare a method like that in TypeScript?

what I want is something like

```
function makenewfunction<T>(fun: T):<U extends function as function(thisarg:any restParam of T):V as return type of T
```

But I can't find an appropriate approach in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This implementation creates a new function that wraps the original function and adds an additional parameter that will serve as the `this` argument for the new function:

```
function makeFn<F extends (...args: any) => any>(fn: F):
    (...args: [unknown, ...Parameters<F>]) => ReturnType<F> {

    return (thisArg, ...args) => fn.call(thisArg, ...args);
}

function fn(this: {property: string}, arg: string) {
    return [this.property, arg].join(' ');
}

const newFn = makeFn(fn);

console.log(newFn({ property: 'Hello' }, 'world!'));
```

<sup>[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=53&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYGsCmAxMAebRTADykzABMBnRACgDpHUAnAcyoC5FUwBPASkQBeAHzc+I2sDBds-DgFgAUIlV1G9Fuy4BtcOjBwA7mAA0iDQAUWqZJjLMqBEQF1BoxACV7IZmAAqvAAOmM6IAN7KymqIzD5+dFAAFjBUAIJs5hpaVO5i0vQQqAA2xbTJqRmsWUxsuQDcygC+UUqgkLAIiNLlKZwRQcxwIcxQvFxUUMwwYKxN5loTUzOsgpEqanFQvkg6FVT0g8OYo7wLbC70AFZwM7QA5Ij3-I1KLUrKEAiTiGCYRrhhCgMDgwFIwC9Wl8wFQ4MVMPRinBWLQ-gCweFEEcRmMuPcABKYUpwR7zJ5GODMYoUACEz0hSiAA)</sup>

Comment: one more question:how can I use this function as extention method, instead of normal function call.

Comment: What's an "extention method"?

Comment: like myfunc.makefn() instead of makefn(myfunc)

Comment: That's an entirely new question though, and it no longer has to do with typing as much as it has to do with adding things to the function's prototype in JavaScript.

Comment: Also, wouldn't that then just be `const newFn = fn.call`?